# QtCreator: Include generated UI files when shadow building

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I'm using QtCreator to develop a larger application which is set up as .pro files with the `SUBDIRS` template.

Some of the sub projects need to include the generated ui_*.h files from other sub projects (e.g. in order to extend a generic GUI class). Each sub project has a line like

```
UI_DIR = gen/ui/$${CONFIGURATION_NAME}
```

where `CONFIGURATION_NAME` is "static_debug" or "static_release".

Now what I usually do is add the following includes when necessary:

```
#if _DEBUG
    #include <OtherProject/gen/ui/static_debug/ui_SomeClass.h>
#else
    #include <OtherProject/gen/ui/static_release/ui_SomeClass.h>
#endif
```

However, this does not work when shadow building, as the generated files are in the shadow build folder while the source files are in the source folder.

Is there a way to make this work with shadow builds, or is there a more sophisticated way to handle such cases in general?

Comment: Here you can find a pretty clean way of setting up the variables you'll need to reference generated files properly: http://qt-project.org/wiki/QMake-top-level-srcdir-and-builddir
Once defined the build dir, you can add `DEFINES+=...` pointing to your build dir to include in your subprojects

Comment: Anyway, QtCreator is irrelevant here. It's all about qmake :)

Comment: Indeed, I only had this problem in QtCreator because that was the only place where I was using shadow builds ;-) Your link is exactly what I needed, create an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SUBDIRS` template is an awesome feature although not documented well enough I think.

Here's a link from the Qt wiki which is of help in this case: http://qt-project.org/wiki/QMake-top-level-srcdir-and-builddir

To re-cap a bit:

**Qt4-based solution**

---

**myproject.pro**

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs
SUBDIRS = initvars.pro subdir1 subdir2 #subdir1 and subdir2 are your project subdirs
```

**initvars.pro**

```
TEMPLATE=subdirs
SUBDIRS= # don't build anything, we're just generating the .qmake.cache file
QMAKE_SUBSTITUTES += .qmake.cache.in
```

**`\.qmake.cache.in`**

```
top_srcdir=$$PWD
top_builddir=$$OUT_PWD
```

---

**Qt5-based solution**

Here things get easier

---

```
top_srcdir=$$PWD
top_builddir=$$shadowed($$PWD)
```

---

Now, having access to the actual build dir, your subprojects will go in the relevant subdirs. You can use this information to fill in the `INCLUDEPATH` in your subprojects `.pro` files to make it easier to include what you need from your sibling projects.

Answer (score 0):

I personally have not had this problem but the problem could be arising because

1. It’s probably looking for them in current dir.Take a look at how you
   include the ui_.h files in your headers.Add UI files path to  qmake’s includepath.
2. You can change where to create them using the UI_DIR variable in
   your .pro file.